# GA4 Event Collection API: What, if any, rate limiting gets applied?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

If you are creating gtag events using POST requests, calling the API that is described here:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/sending-events?client_type=gtag#limitations

Endpoint that we are calling:
https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect

How the request URLS are built:
https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/main/dspace-api/src/main/java/org/dspace/google/client/GoogleAnalytics4ClientRequestBuilder.java

What kind of rate limiting gets applied on these requests?

For **Universal Analytics**, the applicable rate limit algorithm was described on:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/limits-quotas#client_libs_sdks

I was not able to find a corresponding page or details for GA4.

Comment: if you are sending it yourself there wouldn't be any its the libraries themselves that apply any rate limiting.

Comment: I wish you were right but we are currently seeing http connection SSL errors for subsequent calls and we're trying to figure out if rate limiting might be an issue

Comment: post the error message

Comment: GA4 has teh following API/token limits https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/limits-quotas

Comment: @Tushar that seems to be about the Reporting API and not about the events creation API.

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo We are seeing things like 

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake
...
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
...
But we might be swallowing HTTP 429 responses along the way, have not been able to identify them yet.

Comment: edit your question and Include the full request you are sending I want to try it